# Coded UI test Single Thread Apartment (STA) error occurred while executing [ClassCleanup] method

Tags: coded-ui-tests

Why do I get a STA error while my class is performing a clean-up method in a coded UI test but seems the concrete test methods works fine. My code looks like the ff:

```
    [CodedUITest]
    public class ConcreteCUIT : TestBase 
    {
        [ClassInitialize]
        public static void Initialize(TestContext context)
        {
          //do init
        }
        [ClassCleanup]
        public static void CleanUp()
        {
          //do clean-up - STA error!!!
        }
        [TestMethod]
        public void Concrete1CRUDTest()
        {
          //do UI test
        }
        [TestMethod]
        public void Concrete2CRUDTest()
        {
          //do UI test
        }
    }
```

And I got the following error below:

```
Class Cleanup method SampleCUIT.CleanUp failed. Error Message:Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITest.Extension.UITestException: The Coded UI Test is running in Single Thread Apartment (STA) mode of COM.  In this mode, all the playback calls should happen from the TestMethod thread only and UITestControl should not be shared across TestMethods.. 
Stack Trace:
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITest.Playback.ScreenElement.ThrowExceptionIfCrossThreadAccess(IScreenElement uiElement)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITest.Playback.ScreenElement.FindAllScreenElement(String queryId, Int32 depth, Boolean singleQueryId, Boolean throwException)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITest.Playback.ScreenElement.FindScreenElement(String queryId, Int32 depth)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITesting.UITestControl.FindFirstDescendant(String queryId, Int32 maxDepth, Int32& timeLeft)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITesting.SearchHelper.GetElement(Boolean useCache, ISearchArgument searchArg)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITesting.SearchHelper.Search(ISearchArgument searchArg)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITesting.UITestControl.FindInternal()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITesting.UITestControl.FindControlIfNecessary()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITesting.UITestControl.Click(MouseButtons button, ModifierKeys modifierKeys, Point relativeCoordinates)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITesting.Mouse.ClickImplementation(UITestControl control, MouseButtons button, ModifierKeys modifierKeys, Point relativeCoordinate)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITesting.Mouse.ClickImplementationWrapper(UITestControl control, MouseButtons button, ModifierKeys modifierKeys, Point relativeCoordinate)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITesting.Mouse.Click(UITestControl control)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The top line of the stack trace states the problem: "... *all the playback calls should happen from the TestMethod thread*". Later lines of the stack trace show a call of `mouse.click` from the cleanup routine.

Do not call UI actions from the `ClassCleanup` method.